# Http/2 em browsers com http/1.x

Tags: http

Boa noite galera.
Estou com projeto java web onde utilizo o servlet 4.0 e por ele utilizar o http/2 estou com uma dúvida:

O http/2 do meu projeto vai funcionar em browsers com http/1.x como se fosse o http /1?

Não sei se perguntei corretamente.

Comment: Acredito que funcione normalmente só que sem as features do http2

Comment: É provavel que o servelet reconheça pela entrada HTTP da requisição se é 1.0, 1.1 ou 2.0 e então decide como entregar, ou seja `Navegador` => `requisição HTTP` -> `servelet avalia` => após avaliar se é 1.0, 1.1 ou 2.0 será enviado a `RESPOSTA HTTP` necessária para o pedido do cliente/navegador. Ou seja, o projeto é HTTP2, mas isso é para dar suporte ao HTTP2 e não somente suporte ao HTTP2, ou é para incluir.

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação.Então eu preciso codificar meu servlet para que forneça os 2 tipos de http (1.x e 2)?